# how can i prevent overflowing button?

Tags: html, css

how can i prevent overflowing button? i do not know how to solve it...
i tried everything...
or maybe im just stupid or i just dont know a specific solution to fix this

```
.tips input {
    padding: .5em;
    background: var(--verydarkcyan);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--darkgrayfishcyan);
    background: var(--lightgrayfishcyan);
    text-align: center;
}

.tips {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
    gap: .35em
}

.tips button {
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em;
    background: var(--verydarkcyan);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: .7em;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and add relevant HTML

Comment: You can apply additional or separate style to the last buttons. SO you can set the width separately.

Additionally, you can reduce the width of the buttons so that the last buttons can fit easily

Comment: you can give a fixed width to outer div of buttons and decrease the space between buttons

Comment: codesnippet would be nice ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is overflowing because of your `padding: .5em`. The text is bigger than the available space you give it.

There are multiple ways to fix that, here you have two:

**1. Hide overflow**

You can add `overflow: hidden` to your buttons, now to button won't grow with the text.

**2. Give text more space by changing the padding**

You can change `padding: .5em` to `padding-block: .5em`. With that you are setting the padings only on top and bottom of the button, not left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Add a width property to `.tips` class with a fix value or you can use `max-width` in `.tips button` property with a `100% width` to make all buttons of same width